# How to prioritize paying back loans based on interest?

Tags: investing, loans, interest

If I have a loan at 0% and can get a 7% return on my capital, then I wouldn't want to pay back that loan until the absolute last moment.

If I have a loan at 14% and can get 7% return on my capital, then I'd want to pay back the loan immediately.

But what about the in-between? What if I have a 6.9% loan?

- Should I drag it on as long as possible, i.e. should I consider the 7% return on capital as a threshold?
- Should I pay it more quickly than a 6.8% loan, but more slowly than a 7% loan? What would be the appropriate speed to pay back a 6.8% loan?

I'm not looking to have a precise answer to any of those questions, but I'm trying to understand how to model these sorts of situations and how to make the optimal decision in them.

Comment: How much tax do you pay on your investment returns?

Comment: @MikeScott That's a great question, and I don't know! The real world is messy, but the exact numbers here aren't that important. Once I understand how to make these decisions, I can easily redo them for any tax-adjusted return.

Comment: Is the 7% return guaranteed?

Comment: Yes, let's assume that 7% is guaranteed in the long term, i.e. return may be different each year, but overall it will be 7%. Or you can make any other assumption about return you'd like, I'm trying to develop the way I think about these situations more than I have any specific decision to make.

Comment: @user60561 Just a note that you should be careful about the terminology you're using - 7% 'guaranteed in the long term' implies you're considering stock investments, which are *NOT* guaranteed, and there is a good reason that debt rates are lower than equity earnings rates. Don't hand-wave away the lack of guarantee over earnings. The risk between the two is quite different.

Comment: There are situations where the amount you can save between two alternatives wouldn't pay for the food required to replace the calories you burn trying to choose between the two.

Answer (score 3):

If the 7% return were completely risk free (there's no risk of the issuer defaulting, the investment losing value, etc.) Then *mathematically* you'd be better off focusing on whichever rate were higher. So if the investment earned only 0.001% more than the loan you wouldn't more than the minimum payment on the loan.

In reality, there's not a clear answer for several reasons:

- Investments carry *risk* while loans do not. You are going to pay the loan back regardless of any outside factors. Investments have a risk of default (for bonds) and risk of losing value (for stocks) that make it uncertain which is "better".
- Investments have transaction costs that change the return profile depending on the number of transactions you have.
- Loans most often follow an *amortization* schedule, where some of the principal is paid back in addition to interest, resulting in an even payment over the life of the loan. For an investment, that probably means selling an amount equal to the loan payment to be a fair comparison, bringing transaction costs into play.
- You are not going to get a "risk-free" investment that pays more than a loan. Why would banks lend money to you for a lower interest rate than they could get by just parking it in a "risk-free" investment?

Answer (score -1):

If you have a loan that is guaranteed to have 6.999% interest forever, and a savings account that is guaranteed to have 7% interest forever, and some extra money, of course you should put it in the savings account instead of the loan.

If you put $100 in the savings account instead of the loan, it costs you $6.999 per year because you are not paying back the loan as much, but you gain $7.000 per year because it is in the savings account. Thus you make $0.001 profit per year.

In the real world, the savings are not guaranteed, and nor is the loan, and the expected value from a tiny difference would be wiped out by a bad stock year or a loan interest increase and many people would prefer the certainty of being in less debt.

Comment: In many cases, a loan's interest costs *are* guaranteed, so not sure it's fair to make that 'uncertainty' the same as the uncertainty of earnings.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon it's the uncertainty of your income and savings

Comment: The point is that when you pay down a debt, you have a guaranteed rate of return - your interest cost is reduced by the known interest rate. Whereas investment in a non-guaranteed investment has an element of risk. This means that paying down, say, a 4% debt can be preferable to a 7% 'average' return on investment, after factoring risks [how much risk should be valued is a tough question to be answered case-by-case].